# Android handling orientation change, if screen locked

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an Activity for camera, and I wont to lock the orientation for this view. I did it so:

```
[Activity(Label = "Camera Android", MainLauncher = false, NoHistory = false, Theme = "@style/MyThema",
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
    public class FullScreenView : MvxActivity<CameraViewModel>
    {
    ..
    }
```

Now I have 2 problems:
 1 - I want to rotate the icons in this view, if orientation has changed.
 2 - All photos will be saved only in Portrait mode.

This method will be not called, if I write for the activity

> ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
   base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

> OrientationEventListener

don't work too.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with using device accelerometer. 
In project I use Mvvmcross and I installed the MvvmCross Accelerometer plugin.

```
public interface IMvxAccelerometer
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    bool Started {
        get;
    }
    MvxAccelerometerReading LastReading {
        get;
    }
    event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxAccelerometerReading>> ReadingAvailable;
}
```

Than in code I reading X and Y position of my device and change orientation for the icons and stored photo.